# html5 video showing multiples subtitles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

At my Project I have right at the momento two vids with subtitles. I am using html `<video>`, `<source>` and `<track>`.

I have buttoms that makes the user select which video to show. To load the vid I’m using this `jquery` code:

```
$("#sourceVideo").attr("src", urlVideo);
$("#trackSubtitulos").attr("src", urlSub);
$('#video').load();
$('#video').get(0).play()
```

When loading and showing the first vid everything works fine, but once I click on the buttom to select and see next vid (right in the same position), It loads right BUT I see the subtitles from this second vid and first, if a third vid buttom It shows subtitles from the 3 vids and so on…

Could anyone give me a hint to solve this problem or at least tell me why this is happening?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can add multiple tracks to your video. So when you are adding new one, you are not replacing old ones. 
I think the easiest way to get ride of this problem, would be just to hide all previously added subtitles. For example:

```
var video = document.getElementById('idOfYourVideoElement');
for (var i = 0; i < video.textTracks.length; i++) 
    video.textTracks[i].mode = 'hidden';
```